# Reload layers source when launching QGIS Project

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I have a project with some WFS layers from a Geoserver.
Those layers need an authentication, I use the basic authentication from the authentication manager. This authentication is specified in the data source with `authcfg='85zh3v2'`, this number is the id of the authentication used to import the layers into the project, but it's not mine, mine is `63007lo`.

If someone with another id than the one used to import the layers is trying to open the project I use a code snipped to change this id in the data source. On paper it works but QGIS doesn't seem to save the changes in the data source. A window is showed with all the layers as invalid because of the data source and yet I can see in the console that the data source has been changed :

[image: Invalid data source window]

After I close this window all layers are valid and the data source in the properties is correct :

[image: layer properties with valid data source]

Is it possible to reload layers in the project so QGIS can take the data source changes into account and not show the invalid data window?

I tried to use `reload` from [QgsMapLayer](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.10/core/QgsMapLayer.html#qgis.core.QgsMapLayer.reload) and `reloadAllLayers` from [QgsProject](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.10/core/QgsProject.html#qgis.core.QgsProject.reloadAllLayers).

QGIS version : 3.10.9
Windows version : 11

Here is the code I used to change the data source :

```
# Launch the function to find layers from GeoServer and if necessary fix the links
QgsProject.instance().layersAdded.connect(self.checkSource)


def checkSource(self, layers):
    if self.auth:
        for layer in layers:
            if not layer.isValid():
                old_uri = layer.source()
                new_uri = ""
                for elem in old_uri.split(' '):
                    if "authcfg=" in elem:
                        new_uri = new_uri + "authcfg='" + str(self.auth) + "'" + " "
                    else:
                        new_uri = new_uri + ' ' + str(elem)
                name = layer.name()
                provider = layer.providerType()
                options = layer.dataProvider().ProviderOptions()
                layer.setDataSource(new_uri, name, provider, options)
                layer.reload()
    QgsProject.instance().reloadAllLayers()
```